# Showing there exists transitive point

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Suppose $X$ is a non-empty, second-countable Baire topological space. 

 Let $G$ be a countable collection of continuous functions $g_i:X \rightarrow X$, where $i=1,2,\dots$, such that the system $(X,g_i)$ is topologically transitive for all $i=1,2,\dots$.

 I would like to show that there exists a point $x \in X$ such that $x$ is $g_i$-transitive for all $i=1,2,\dots$.

 Since $(X,g_i)$ is topologically transitive for all $i=1,2,\dots$, we have that for any non-empty open sets $U,V$ in $X$, there exist infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g_i^n(U) \cap V \neq \emptyset$, or equivalently $U \cap g_i^{-n}(V) \neq \emptyset$. That is, for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq m$ such that $g_i^n(U) \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

 I need to show there is a point $x \in X$ such that the omega-limit set of $X$, $\omega(x)=X$.
That means that for all $U \subseteq X$ non-empty and open and for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n \geq m$ such that $g_i^n(x)\in U$.

 I am not sure how to choose this $x$.

Comment: $f=g_i$ in the middle paragraph? Can you define $\omega(x)$?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: The omega-limit set $\omega(x)$ of a point $x$ in a dynamical system $(X,f)$ is defined as $\omega(x)=\cap_{n=0}^\infty \overline{f^n(\mathcal{O}_f(x))}$, where $\mathcal{O}_f(x)$ is the orbit of $x$ under $f$.

Comment: The $x$ is probably from a countable intersection of dense and open sets, which is non-empty (even dense) in a Baire space.. The countable base also has to be used somewhere...

Comment: Let $G=\{g_i:X \rightarrow X \mid g_i \text{ is continuous}\}$. A point $x \in X$ is $g_i$-transitive for all $i$ if and only if $\omega_{g_i}(x)=X$ for all $i$. Thus I have to show that the set $A=\{x\in X \mid \omega_{g_i}(x)=X \text{ for all } i\}$ is non-empty.

Comment: We have $A=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{x \in X \mid \omega_{g_i}(x)=X\}$

Comment: $A=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{x \in X \mid \text{for all } B \in \mathcal{B} \text{ and for all } m \in \mathbb{N}, \text{ there exists } n \geq m \text{ such that } x \in g_i^{-1}(B) \}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a base of $X$

Comment: $A=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \cap_{B \in \mathcal{B}} \cap_{m=0}^{\infty} \cup_{n=m}^{\infty} g_i^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: How do I show this set is non-empty?

Comment: show that all sets in the intersection are open and dense?